# AS3 KeyboardEvents not firing until after I've clicked on an onscreen button

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So here's my setup:

My document class is Main.as (it extends MovieClip). The following code is in my Main.as.

I've declared all these variables in my class definition:

```
private var holder:MovieClip;
private var leftButton:SimpleButton;
private var rightButton:SimpleButton;
```

in constructor...

```
holder = new MovieClip();
addChild(holder);
holder.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyboardEvent);

leftButton = new Arrow();
rightButton = new Arrow();

holder.addChild(leftButton);
holder.addChild(rightButton);

leftButton.x = 50;
leftButton.rotation = 180;
rightButton.x = 150;

leftButton.y = rightButton.y = 50;

leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handlePaging);
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handlePaging);
```

...outside of constructor...

```
public function handleKeyboardEvent ( e:KeyboardEvent ) {
            trace("got a keyboard event");

                trace("e.charCode : " + e.charCode);
                trace("e.keyCode : " + e.keyCode);
                switch (e.keyCode) {
                    case 37: //left arrow
                        showPreviousMoment();
                        break;
                    case 39: //right arrow
                        showNextMoment();
                        break;
                }


        }
```

The two buttons are instances of an Arrow movieclip that I have in the library. The Arrow movie clip just has graphics in it (in the property dialog for it the base class is flash.display.SimpleButton).

I want the user to be able to press the onscreen arrows OR the keyboard arrow keys to page forwards and backwards.

So...when I test the movie or publish it as an app, pressing the left and right keyboard keys doesn't do anything. HOWEVER...AFTER I click on the screen arrows THEN the keyboard events are getting picked up!!!  How come my keyboard events are not getting received initially? Why does clicking on the onscreen buttons make the 'holder' start receiving the events?

**UPDATE**

I've also just commented out all of my code EXCEPT for the instantiating the 'holder' and adding the listener.
The KeyboardEvents are not being heard by the holder.

**UPDATE...ANSWER**

So I found out that if I want to globally hear the KeyboardEvent, I should register stage as the listener. So this did the trick:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyboardEvent);
```

Info from Colin Moock's book:

> Keyboard-input events that trigger
>   application-wide commands are
>   typically handled globally, by
>   listeners registered with Flash
>   Player's Stage instance. By contrast,
>   keyboard-input events that trigger a
>   specific interface-element response
>   are typically handled by listeners
>   registered with the object that
>   currently has keyboard focus.

So I guess that in my initial version, when I clicked on the onscreen arrow button, I somehow gave keyboard focus to the 'holder;.

Comment: Are you sure it is the clicking the arrows that makes the keyboard events work and not just clicking anything in the flash movie? 'Cause it sounds like you need to have the flash window in focus for the keyboard events to work. Try clicking on something else in the flash movie (not the arrows) and then test clicking your keyboard arrows, if this works it means there is nothing wrong with your code and everything works like it is supposed to.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is not a focus issue. I've clicked on different parts of the movie window and that wouldn't 'activate' the keys. It's only AFTER I click on the onscreen buttons...then the keys are active.

Comment: Could you add the handlePaging function to the question? maybe it is something in there that activates the keyboard events. (just a wild guess)

Comment: I knew it had something to do with focus. Maybe not focus on the flash window, but the holder mc. =D
And since the arrows are inside the holder, you technically are clicking the holder when you click the arrows, giving focus to the proper mc.

Comment: Post the answer yourself and mark is accepted, you figured it out legitimately and if the problem is solved then the question needs to show that it has been answered. :)

Answer (score 4):

Ususally the object you click on gets the focus. This really affects listeners, that's why it works when you add it to the stage.

When you clicked on any of those, your "holder" object got the focus, therefore the event fired. Now you do it well, that you added it to the stage.

Comment: Two main properties determine whether interaction causes focus changes. mouseEnabled (when false) stops both mouse and keyboard events. Assuming mouseEnabled is true, any InteractiveObject subclass (TextFields, Sprites, MovieClips, etc.) can be manually assigned the focus via stage.focus property. HOWEVER, by default, objects (except TextField and SimpleButton) will NOT automatically receive the focus when clicked unless "tabEnabled" is set to true.  When buttonMode is true, tabEnabled becomes true. In summary, tabEnabled's value determines whether click or tab may give an object focus.

Answer (score 3):

A more dynamic solution (say if you dynamically instance a class which contains a movieclip) is to use:

```
stage.focus = this;
```

So if you apply the event listener to the class instance that actually needs to listen to key events, this might work better for you.

For me the previous suggestions didn't work as I was adding my main class instance at run-time. In the end I my code looked like this:

```
Main.singletron.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyDown);
Main.singletron.stage.focus = this;
```

...you'll have to set up a singletron for those 2 lines to work.

Comment: singletron, lol. it should be singleTON https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer to my own question based on @Ascension Systems recommendation. I'm just really copying from my update to my question above.

**UPDATE...ANSWER**

So I found out that if I want to globally hear the KeyboardEvent, I should register stage as the listener. So this did the trick:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, handleKeyboardEvent);
```

Info from Colin Moock's book:

> Keyboard-input events that trigger
>   application-wide commands are
>   typically handled globally, by
>   listeners registered with Flash
>   Player's Stage instance. By contrast,
>   keyboard-input events that trigger a
>   specific interface-element response
>   are typically handled by listeners
>   registered with the object that
>   currently has keyboard focus.

So I guess that in my initial version, when I clicked on the onscreen arrow button, I somehow gave keyboard focus to the 'holder'.